# How can I call context menu for image saving inside Ionic application?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, safari, contextmenu, save-as

If I go to Safari mobile (iOS 11+) browser and land on www.google.com - I can long press on google's logo (img element) and call "context menu":

[image]

Now I want to do the same for an img element inside Ionic's page (regardless whether its PWA or hybrid app).

How would I achieve that?

I guess Ionic or Angular has a lot of configurations to prevent default behaviors for touch etc inputs, but since I see I can do it with google.com via normal browser I guess we can override some setting and achieve the same?

By default if I create a blank app and place any img into it I can get context menu on desktop but not on Safari mobile.

Code wise I looked at google's page and this should be just any img element, something like this:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h2>Try to call context menu here:</h2>
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
</ion-content>
```

This does not work for ios 11 webview by default and I think its hammer.js or maybe ionic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I figured out how to do this.
So first thing - make sure you are not preventingDefault behavior on contextmenu in your app. For example I had this code below to prevent weird with context menu etc:

```
if ("oncontextmenu" in window) {
      window.oncontextmenu = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
      };
};
```

Now by default in your android app the long press (touch) over actual `<img>` will call a context menu which user can use to save image.

With iOS you also need to set this CSS prop on image:

```
img {
        -webkit-touch-callout: default !important;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

With this you can achieve users calling the context menu to save images using standard platform UI. There is no other good UX I am aware off on iOS to "save" image right now (downloads basically open images in new window...)

Comment: Great find on -webkit-touch-callout!

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins like [LongPress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-long-press)

```
npm i ionic-long-press
```

and then just run [ActionSheet](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/action-sheet/ActionSheetController/) plugin

Comment: So the Ionic’s action sheet is not the same as system’s action sheet here. The former is just a ui component, while i need to get to the system method of saving picture. Also the long press plugin is to help call buttons in intervals.

Comment: You could use also native ActionSheet, but ActionSheet is not for saving images it is only menu that slides up when you are giving user possibility to do something. Whole implementation of saving picture is different topic. 
E.g. You can look for base64-to-gallery plugin